# \chapter unrecognized command in TeXstudio but not in overleaf

Tags: chapters, texstudio, overleaf

I recently switched to TeXstudio because I am required to not put up my thesis online. I am using my document class I always used, but now \chapter is marked as \chapter unrecognized command. I already checked online for solutions, which usually stated that the person is using the wrong baseclass, however, I am using scrbook as baseclass and to my knowledge \chapter should be defined here. Also, the chapter command does work in the file and in the table of contents, it is just marked, which makes me wonder.

```
\ProvidesClass{thesis}

\newcommand{\baseclass}{scrbook}
\DeclareOption*{
    \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\baseclass}
}
\PassOptionsToClass{
    oneside,
    paper=a4,
    parskip,
    listof=totoc,
    headings=small,
    BCOR=10mm
}{\baseclass}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{\baseclass}

%Packages
%...
```

What I am wondering the most about is, that this class works in overleaf (still right now, just checked it), but does not work with chapters in TeXstudio.

Does anyone know where the problem might be?

Comment: if "marked" means that texstudio highlights it somehow: ignore that. Try to compile, if you don't get an error everything is fine.

Comment: Ok, then thank you! The commands work out fine (at least up to now), then I will just ignore it.

Comment: You can write your own completion file `thesis.cwl` that will make `\chapter` recognized. See details in the [user manual](https://texstudio-org.github.io/background.html#description-of-the-cwl-format). In this case it will just need to contain the line `\chapter{title}#L1`